# Iterate through local Swift packages

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I have a bunch of local Swift packages in my project. Some of them are third party, but I have made some modifications to them to suit my needs. I want to display them in a list of acknowledgements in the About section of the app. The local packages are present inside a Packages folder on the same level as the project file. It is added to the project but isn't added to the Bundle. *I don't want local packages to be added to the bundle resources*.

So far I have been able to make it work on the simulator using the following logic:

```
static func parsePackagesFolder() -> [Package?] {
    var localPackages = [Package]()
    let packagesFolderPath = projectRoot.appendingPathComponent("Packages").path
    let enumerator = FileManager().enumerator(atPath: packagesFolderPath)
    while let element = enumerator?.nextObject() as? String {
        if let fType = enumerator?.fileAttributes?[FileAttributeKey.type] as? FileAttributeType {
            switch fType {
            case .typeDirectory:
    
                let directoryPath = packagesFolderPath + "/\(element)"
                if let licenseContent = fetchLicenseContent(path: directoryPath) {
                    // <create package instance and append to list>
                    localPackages.append(package)
                }
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    return localPackages
}
```

`Package` is a data structure I've defined. `fetchLicenseContent()` looks for the license file for the local packages and returns the text content of the file. `projectRoot` is determined as follows:

```
static var projectRoot: URL {
    let thisFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: #file)
    var rootLocation = thisFile
    while rootLocation.lastPathComponent != "<App directory name>" {
        rootLocation = rootLocation.deletingLastPathComponent()
    }
    return rootLocation
}
```

This logic fails on the physical device. The `enumerator` returns nil, so it can't parse `nextObject()`. I tried using `FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath` instead of `projectRoot`, but that doesn't work either on simulator or on device.
It's obvious that the path for the Packages folder is different on the actual device. How can I get the path for the Packages folder on the physical device?

Comment: "I don't want local packages to be added to the bundle resources." Then from *where* is your code going to read the license info? The thing you want to read is literally not *on* the device.

Comment: This sort of thing is usually a build script. It isn't something your _app_ does. That would be crazy.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll try doing this with a build script.